# mysqlDB, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'Decimal'

Tags: python, mysql-python, fetchall

Here is my `SQL`:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT sk, SUM(qty) AS cnt FROM order WHERE sk LIKE '%s%s' AND days <= '%s' GROUP BY sk ORDER by cnt DESC) AS tmp WHERE tmp.cnt >3;
```

and here is my code:

```
result = cur.fetchall()
for sk, cnt in result:
    rat = cnt/total
```

then I get a error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'Decimal'
```

I have no idea why `cnt` is type `str` instead of `int`.

Comment: Try to use `rat = int(cnt) / total`

Comment: that not help. If change it to rat = int(cnt) / total , then another error occurred:  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'cnt'

Comment: what are the types of both cnt & toatal try int(cnt)/int(toatl).

Comment: what I got through fetchall() was a list of dict, so cnt in result is just the key of one of the dict, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem: each row of the `fetchall()` is a `dict` which looks like `{'sk': u'S0013', 'cnt': Decimal('1971')}` so `cnt` in result is the `key` of the `dict` instead of `value`..